# unexpected T_VARIABLE line 12

Tags: php

This is my code. I am extremely new at this, less than 2 weeks and I know there is a syntax error in here somewhere but it keeps telling me T_variable is unexpected on line 12. It matches the "...input type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name...\" info so can someone help a little? Noob needs help! Just a little...? Anything you can tell me will be very much appreciated.

```
<?
$correct = true;
if ($_GET["name"] == "")
    $correct = false;
if (preg_match("/^.+@\w+\.\w{2,4}$/", $_GET["email"]))
    $correct = false;

$to = "sample@domain.com";
$subject = "Application request";

$message = "A new request has come in!;\n\n"
$message .= $_GET["firstname"].;
$message .= $_GET["lastname"].;

$message .= $_GET["email"]."\n";

$message .= $_GET["phone"]."\n";
$message .= $_GET["dropdown"]."\n";
$message .= $_GET["address"]."\n";
$message .= $_GET["dropdown2"]."\n";
$message .= $_GET["textarea"]."\n";


(mail($to, $subject, $message);

?>

<body>
<? if ($correct): ?>
Thank you for applying. We will get back to you shortly.<br>
<? if else: ?>
Please complete the form.
</ end if ?>




</body>
```

Comment: I don't mean to discourage using SO, but please continue to RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems:

1

```
$message = "A new request has come in!;\n\n"
```

Should become:

```
$message = "A new request has come in!;\n\n";
```

2.

```
$message .= $_GET["firstname"].;
```

Should become:

```
$message .= $_GET["firstname"];
```

Comment: OP is concatenating. This has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO WRONG - he has semi colons after each line. I'm talking  about the `.` at the end. You down-voted without closely reading my answer when my answer is not only correct but will save the OP errors in the future

Comment: Before you edited your answer.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO No, my original answer was correct too. The only thing I edited was also including the error on line 12. Regardless, the answer is correct, there is no reason for the down vote.

Comment: I still don't think that there should be a semi-colon inside this string... `"A new request has come in!;\n\n";`

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone! I've updated the code, removed what needed to be removed and moved over a semicolon, now I get this: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE, expecting '(' in /home/content/91/10533591/html/application.php on line 30..." The <? end if ?>... how is this wrong? I've used this before. Not in PHP but in VB. Is the syntax wrong?! by the way, the :\n\n"; worked. well, it didn't give me that error anyway.

Comment: @user1739280 - REmove the "If" part of "if else"

Comment: lol, okay. done. Now it tells me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/content/91/10533591/html/application.php on line 35..." I've been at this since 2am!! lmao! im ready to shoot this f#*&$% virtual library!!!! I think I'm delirious! this is the section it doesn't like: 
    <? if ($correct): ?>
 Thank you for applying. We will get back to you shortly.<br>
    <? else: ?>
 Please complete the form.
    <? end ?>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: @user1739280 You're missing the `<?php` `?>` tags ...

Comment: @user1739280 Here is correct code.. http://pastebin.com/5g1qjivw

Comment: That code was the original with just PHP added on. I made the adjustments with PHP, but... nada. Still tells me: "unexpected $end"

Comment: @user1739280 Mark this answer, and then open up a new question with the *new* issues and I'll be glad to check it out there. This is getting too cluttered. In the new post put your most updated code. thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840027/php-syntax-error-unexpected-end-line-36

Comment: @user1739280 Thanks please mark this question to close it.

Comment: Answer isn't correct if OP's code isn't working.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I answered 10 questions ... the first question was answered a long time ago. Me and you both know that if the OP has moer questions, he should open a new thread

Answer (score 1):

Semi colon is in the wrong place

```
$message = "A new request has come in!;\n\n"
                                      ^
```

Should be:

```
$message = "A new request has come in!\n\n";
                                           ^
```

You also have erroneous periods:

```
$message .= $_GET["firstname"].;
$message .= $_GET["lastname"].;
                             ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message .= $_GET["firstname"].;
                              ^ Remove
$message .= $_GET["lastname"].;
                             ^ Remove

$message = "A new request has come in!;\n\n"
                                            ^ -> semicolon here 
(mail($to, $subject, $message);
^ -> remove this
```