# php syntax error, unexpected $end line 36

Tags: php

Okay, the original suggestions seemed to work. No error codes for them like before. But now its telling me its not ending well. I've tried multiple syntax but nothing seems to work. and an IF take it away... even removing the `<? end if ?>` or whatnot. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$correct = true;
if ($_GET["firstname"] == "")
    $correct = false;
if (preg_match("/^.+@\w+\.\w{2,4}$/", $_GET["email"]))
    $correct = false;

$to = "sample@domain.com";
$subject = "Application request";

$message = "A new request has come in!\n\n";
$message .= $_GET["firstname"];
$message .= $_GET["lastname"];"\n";
$message .= $_GET["email"];"\n";
$message .= $_GET["phone"];"\n";
$message .= $_GET["dropdown"];"\n";
$message .= $_GET["address"];"\n";
$message .= $_GET["dropdown2"];"\n";
$message .= $_GET["textarea"];"\n";

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>something funky
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if ($correct): ?>
Thank you for applying. We will get back to you shortly.<br>
<?php else: ?>
Please complete the form.
<?php end ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why so against curly brackets?

Comment: i have never seen syntax like <?php else: ?> for PHP. Are you sure it is right ?

Comment: @CodeMonkey that is a valid syntax

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Yes: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: you just need to close your if statement with `endif;`

Comment: @CodeMonkey When using HTML inside a PHP page, it's "recommended" to use this kind of syntax within the HTML code.

Comment: `if():` is terminated with `endif`, not `end`

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
<?php end ?>
```

by

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
$message .= $_GET["lastname"];"\n";
```

You must replace the semi colon with a dot character:

```
$message .= $_GET["lastname"] . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `endif`. Try this,

```
 <?php if ($correct): ?>
    Thank you for applying. We will get back to you shortly.<br>
    <?php else: ?>
    Please complete the form.
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Should be `endif` not `end if`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Realized and Corrected it.

Comment: Your still missing the ; at the end of endif

Comment: @DavidBélanger Feel bad about myself. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @David: AFIK, the semicolon is optional in this case (I'm not saying it's not good to add it, but it is not *necessary*).

Comment: @FelixKling I didn't, I'll try it. Thanks, didn't know it !

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<?php if ($correct): ?>
Thank you for applying. We will get back to you shortly.<br>
<?php else: ?>
Please complete the form.
<?php end ?>
```

To

```
if($correct){
// thank you for ...
}

else{
// please complete
}
```

Comment: I realize his syntax is acceptable, I Just prefer this way :)

Comment: @FelixKling And that's why *they* allow both versions ;)

Comment: Should be `endif;`, though

Comment: @DamienPirsy It's completely different syntax ...

Answer (score 0):

so you can use it:

```
<body>
<?php if ($correct) { ?>
Thank you for applying. We will get back to you shortly.<br>
<?php } else { ?>
Please complete the form.
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

it is untidy but it works fine

you can also write it so

```
<body>
<?php
if ($correct) echo "Thank you for applying. We will get back to you shortly.<br>";
else echo "Please complete the form.";
?>
</body>
```